# How much does it cost to get a visitor visa on arrival in Qatar?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, qatar

I am aware that it is possible to get a visa on arrival but I was wondering if anybody could find a source that says how much it costs.

Citizenship: Canada

City of Departure: SFO

Comment: AFAIK, it costs $30

Comment: Damn. That's pretty cheap. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Qatar e-government website](http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/topics/Visas,+Passports,+Official+Documents/visas):

> Residents of the 33 approved countries can obtain a Tourist Visa upon arrival. The visa can be purchased for a nominal fee at the airport or port. It can also be issued online instantly prior to travel. This visa is valid for one month and cannot be extended.

The [visa costs](http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/services/inviduallandingpages/entry%20visas/tourist%20visa/!ut/p/a1/tVJNc4IwEP0rXDw6WcJHwxEda7WiVWsFLk5EPmIhIARa--sbbA_twY-LmclMNvvmvX27i3zkIp_ThsVUsJzTtI19c2PNSF8lBIazyUCD0dIe9abOowqvGlojH_kJi5NUXjGvw_KIvJCL8qi8sYq22YCLQiTIS-r3PM-Y8hFulSDnQqI68PvZgSosGxaEVQcY37GG7WqaKimVbx4rBY3bzA9vI3llIPK6ZJU4ha1MEbAd8izdVDVMQFeBaqaBt1uMo8jQwbJMEoAhHXnSEZw5Ntxk-ArDCWCChW2H6KvFpEdg9PxkGNMh1mBoIE_W8HBWRNPQsuVY953NfDVYSPTlBt_o_LLqGN9HdXytoXIguHT6TiwpqUi6jEc5cv-MGrn_Ri3xbH84-LbcrHaLPgVy77laRZYRLeu6sDeK_VeUZS_Tru-R6hsVJV_r/dl5/d5/L0lDUmlTUSEhL3dHa0FKRnNBLzRKVXBDQSEhL2Vu/?changeLanguage=en) are:

> Fees
>
> Visa issuance fees: **QR 100 for each visa**, **QR 50 for each accompanying person** and **QR 200 for overstay fine per day**.

At the current exchange rate this works out to ~28`USD`.

This visa is valid for one month and non-extendable.